# DB2 EBCDIC value function

Tags: sql, db2

How do I modify the following SQL to return the EBCDIC (or should it be ASCI?) value of the first character of the selected column>?

```
select  
 substr(PLAN_SLD_CHNL_CD,1,1) 

from 
GG60.SUSP_LOG_HDR SUSP_LOG_HDR
```

I'm very very new to DB2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ASCII value, you can use the `ASCII` function:

```
select ASCII(substr(PLAN_SLD_CHNL_CD,1,1))
from GG60.SUSP_LOG_HDR SUSP_LOG_HDR
```

Actually, this will also work:

```
select ASCII(PLAN_SLD_CHNL_CD)
from GG60.SUSP_LOG_HDR SUSP_LOG_HDR
```

But I prefer the first version, because it is more explicit about what it is doing (converting the first character to its ASCII code).

If you want to convert the string to EBCDIC, then use the `EBCDIC_str()` function.